# Kernel Feature needed to change framebuffer colors?

Tags: linux-kernel, framebuffer

I'm trying to change the colors in the virtual terminal. So far I've tried:

- `echo -en "\e]PXYYYYYY"`-style escapes
- writing to `/sys/module/vt/parameters/default{red,grn,blu}`
- the `PIO_CMAP` ioctl

At this point I'm suspecting that there's a kernel feature I'm missing. My current kernel config is [here](https://hastebin.com/raw/kuvijugapo), my `uname -r` is `4.9.95-gentoo`.

Comment: You're getting ahead of yourself.  (-:  The first question to be asking is whether your framebuffer is even in an indexed colour mode in the first place.

Comment: I don't know what that even means, so you're probably right :P

Comment: @JdeBP I can confirm (color) images in w3m work, so it's not in text mode, at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was an issue with my setup -- [redshift](https://github.com/jonls/redshift) seems to block `\e]R` from working.